# C# When adding a referenced assembly it is throwing a file not found error

Tags: c#

I have a program that dynamically runs user entered C# code, that part works fine and the results are outputted to a location given by the user (or a system default).

My users are asking that I output the results to an "output window" so they can view the results without having to go to file.

I am trying to reference the program the dynamically created C# code is being generated in so I can output the results, but I am getting a file not found error when trying to add the reference for the program that it is being run in.

Here is my code:

```
 private static Assembly CompileSourceCodeDom(string sourceCode)
 {
     CodeDomProvider cpd = new CSharpCodeProvider();
     var cp = new CompilerParameters();
     LogConsoleMessage(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase + "\n");
     cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
     cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
     cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
     cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

     cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
     CompilerResults cr = cpd.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceCode);
     cr.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => 
     LogConsoleMessage(error.ErrorText + " Line #: " + error.Line + " Column: 
      " + error.Column + "\n"));
     if (cr.Errors.Count == 0)
     {
        return cr.CompiledAssembly;
     }
     else
     {
        return null;
     }
  }
```

This is the line where the error is being displayed

```
cr.Errors.Cast<ComplierErrors>().ToList().ForEach(error => 
 LogConsoleMessage(error.ErrorText + " Line #: " + error.Line + " Column: 
  " + error.Column + "\n")); is where the error message is coming out
```

Here is the exact error message. I checked the folder and it does exists.
Metadata file 'file:///C:/Users/[my user]/source/repos/test/test/bin/Debug/test.exe' could not be found Line #: 0 Column: 0

Does this have to do with the fact that the program is currently running? Because I cannot seem to find a way to reference this code. Does anyone have any suggestions about a different way to output the results to a visible location?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

was changed to

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: Your problem might be that `CodeBase` returns the assembly path formatted as a URI (`file://...`) which is not exactly a valid local or UNC path. Try using `Location` instead of CodeBase.

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Assembly.CodeBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx) returns the assembly location formatted as an URI like `file://...` which the compiler is apparently not able to parse.

Instead, try using the "pure" local or UNC path of your assembly. To get the local or UNC path of the assembly, replace *CodeBase* with the [`Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property:

```
LogConsoleMessage(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\n");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```